# formula - Standard deviation based on 2 conditions

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a formula that will provide the standard deviation based on two conditions - I am able to add the condition where equal to a cell value (T2), but I would like to also add where L3:L2987 <>0.  I continue to get parsing errors....here is the original formula (google sheet)

=iferror(arrayformula(STDEV.S(if($D$3:$D$2978=$T3,$L$3:$L$2978))),"--")

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IFERROR(STDEV.S(FILTER(L3:L, L3:L<>0, D3:D=O3)), "--")
```

[image]

Comment: both return '--'

Comment: @LFranco can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: anonymized sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LcJU3wUUqsOFLxMF3syQMwDiH-c_5TUAhC2FxoMj4_g/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(T3,D3:D2978,0),0)*IFERROR(MATCH(0,L3:L2987,0)*0,1),STDEV.S(L3:L2978),"--")
```

**To explain the condition:**

```
IFERROR(MATCH(T3,D3:D2978,0),0)
```

MATCH searches D3:D2978 for a value equal to T3 and returns N/A if value is not found. IFERROR will return 0 if MATCH returns N/A.

Same principle with `IFERROR(MATCH(0,L3:L2987,0)*0,1)`, but the multiply by 0 will ensure that FALSE (0) is returned when a 0 was found on the range. It will return 1 if MATCH returns N/A.

Multiply works as an AND operator.

If both conditions are non-zero, return `STDEV.S(L3:L2978)`, else `--`.

**Sample Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

arrayformula of `stdev.s` is nowdays possible:

```
=BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(D3:D, D3:D<>"")), 
 LAMBDA(xx, IFERROR(STDEV.S(FILTER(L3:L, L3:L<>0, D3:D=xx)), "--")))
```

[image]